# How to get Values from dictionary by specifying timestamp as key value.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am creating a dictionary by iterating over Series Object. The Series looks like this.

```
2018-02-05 00:00:00+00:00    4803.0
2018-02-05 00:15:00+00:00    4803.0
2018-02-05 00:30:00+00:00    4806.0
2018-02-05 00:45:00+00:00    4806.0
Freq: 15T, Name: Biomass, dtype: float64
```

Creating a dictionary by providing the Index as key and data as Value, the dictionary looks like this.

```
print(Entsoe.dictionary_value)

 {Timestamp('2018-02-05 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='15T'): 4803.0,
 Timestamp('2018-02-05 00:15:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='15T'): 4803.0,
 Timestamp('2018-02-05 00:30:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='15T'): 4806.0,
 Timestamp('2018-02-05 00:45:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='15T'): 4806.0}
```

Dictionary is a class member, so accessing using Class name 'Entsoe'

Printing the key and value pair separately using this code.

```
for key in Entsoe.dictionary_value:
       print(f"key: {key}, value: {Entsoe.dictionary_value[key]}")
```

Output result like this,

```
key: 2018-02-05 00:00:00+00:00, value: 4803.0
key: 2018-02-05 00:15:00+00:00, value: 4803.0
key: 2018-02-05 00:30:00+00:00, value: 4806.0
key: 2018-02-05 00:45:00+00:00, value: 4806.0
```

But when tried to access using the key value like this getting the value

> 'None'

```
print(Entsoe.dictionary_value.get('2018-02-05 00:00:00+00:00'))
```

Can somebody explain to me what went wrong here.

Comment: Your keys in the `Entsoe` dictionary are currently `Timestamp` objects and not just strings that represent certain timestamps. Try `print(Entsoe.dictionary_value.get(Timestamp('2018-02-05 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='15T')))`

Comment: @Chillie So do i need to convert the key to `Timestamp` Object now.

Comment: You have it `s.to_dict()
`

Comment: @Chillie tried your solution showing `Unresolved Timestamp reference Error`

Comment: @Wen What is `s` here, can you elaborate your answer.

Comment: @PraveenRB your Series

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to use `Timestamp` objects as dictionary keys instead of actual timestamps?

Comment: @Chillie I got the solution, need to import `Timestamp` module from `Pandas` before using your answer.

Comment: @Chillie I am creating the Dictionary from the `Series` object, so i am not creating here.

Comment: @Chillie do you know the best solution to replace `Timestamp` object by just `timestamp`.

Comment: 1. Please show us the code for `I am creating a dictionary by iterating over Series Object` 2. Is there any documentation to read about `Timestamp` object's attributes? If not, you can first use `dir(Timestamp)` to find out what attributes it has and then use the required attribute when creating the dictionary.

Comment: @Chillie `for i, v in Series.items():` and then `Entsoe.dictionary_value[i] = v`. Like this creating dictionary.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is to use `Entsoe.dictionary_value[str(i)] = v`. This uses the built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-str). However, please try to find out the proper attributes of `Timestamp` and use them instead of this work-around.